# MpAndroid CandleStick Chart, to see the last values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using `MPAndroidChart` Library's Candle `Stick Chart`.
Like I am showing financial data from year 2011 tills date for every 10 minutes.
So I have lots of candle data in one screen.
I have zoomed in the values using,

```
candleStickChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(10, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
candleStickChart.setScaleMinima(150f, 1.5f);
```

But I have to scroll to right to see the last candle data.
I have gone through the documentations, but not able to get how to fix the screen to latest data to swipe to left to see the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
mChart.moveViewToX(xVals.size());
//Here mChart is your chart object and xVals contains values of X axis.
```

This answer will solve your problem.

> **Edit 1:**

```
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(7);
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(7);
```

This will show maximum and minimum 7 candles in screen at a time. To view more you have to swipe.

Comment: Thanks Dhruv.
candleStickChart.setScaleMinima(150f, 1.5f); one more logical error i am also getting. like this is zooming my candle dataset. but this is not giving me the proper resolution, Can u please suggest me which method i shd use for zooming the dataset chart

Comment: Accept the answer if it is useful.

Comment: It did solved my right index problem. can u please suggest me the method to zoom in the candle dataset

Comment: Thanks Dhruva for your kindness, but if i am setting Xrange Max and Min i am not getting any dhart, its drawing like a line

Comment: Try to remove `candleStickChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(10, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT); candleStickChart.setScaleMinima(150f, 1.5f);` and check.

Comment: I removed setScaleMinima, but its not zooming, still its showing a line on x-axis and Y,\

Comment: Sorry, but I have tried with this in BarChart and it is working properly for me.

Comment: candleStickChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        candleStickChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        candleStickChart.setDescription("");
        candleStickChart.setPinchZoom(true);
        candleStickChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(20);
        YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
        candleStickChart.setScaleMinima(150f, 1.5f);
        candleStickChart.setNoDataText("");
        candleStickChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(20);
        candleStickChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(20); have a look at this, where i am dpoing mistake

Comment: Remove `candleStickChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(20);` and try again. I not sure for this.

Comment: Hello Dhruva, thank you very much for your kindness, i removed some methods, and xRangeMaximum did worked for me. Awesome