# Mpandroidchart scroll when zoom

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using a MpAndroidChart's LineChart , I'm trying to find a way to know , in the situation when the chart is zoomed, when the scroll reaches the end in each direction. I noticed that when the scroll is ended on the bottom side or left side , respectively the methods `chart.getViewPortHandler().getTransX()` and `getViewPortHandler().getTransY()` return 0, so in this case I know what I need to know.

What I am not finding is the way to know when the scroll ends on the right side and top side, in this cases the value returned by those methods are numbers that I cannot interpretate (EG: they are not equals to the ViewPort size, they are not equal to the chart's size multiplied by the scale factor).

Is there a way to do this?

thank for any help

EDIT:
I'll try to explain better: I zoom the chart and I start navigating it by scrolling. Let's say I want to see the most right part of the zoomed chart, I have to scroll to left untill I reach the end of the chart. When the most right part of the chart is shown , if I continue scrolling left, the chart will not scroll anymore in that direction. How can I know when this happens?

Comment: As I understand from your question, you want to scroll to the end. Right? If so, please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387867/mpandroid-candlestick-chart-to-see-the-last-values/37388028#37388028

Comment: hello @Dhruv , I edited the question to explain better which are my needs